# Extend a $C^2$ function from the Boundary to the Interior while Preserving Some Regularity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, sobolev-spaces, trace

Let $U$ be some open connected bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^2$ boundary and $g \in C^2(\partial U)$. Can we extend $g$ to the interior of $U$ such that ${extension}(g) \in W^{2, 2}(U)$? I am aware of the Whitney's Extension Theorem, but we have a much stronger hypothesis and weaker requirement here. Is there a way to do this while not using Whitney's Extension?

Comment: I think Whitney's theorem might be overkill here: Using a smooth partition of unity you can reduce matters to such an extension in a neighborhood of a boundary point. Since $\partial U$ is $C^2$ you can flatten the boundary (near the aforementioned boundary point) and further reduce matters to the case $U$ is the upper half-space and $g$ with compact support. You can then extend in a myriad of ways (though if you want explicit control on the $W^{2,2}$ norm you'll have to work harder, but I don't see why it shouldn't be possible)

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you very much for the comment. Could you elaborate a little bit more on this process? I am aware of this technique of reducing from the full domain to the half-plane, but I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Evans' PDE book, particularly the section on Sobolev spaces, the theorem where he extends a function in $W^{1,p}(U)$ to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, he does this flattening procedure in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: @Jose27 It is not clear if I could modify the proof from Evans. Since our function is only defined on the boundary, we can't really do a reflection construction like Evans.

Comment: I meant to reference that only for the flattening part. An extension in your case is easier: Just make the extension constant in the transversal direction.